# Quartz Cron expression at 45 minutes at hourly intervals

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I want to write an hourly cronExpression for hourly jobs but at 45 minutes every hour. For example 7:45, 8:45, 9:45 etc. How can I achieve that.

My attempt using Quartz

0 45/45 * ? * * *

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. For anyone interested,

expression should be 0 45/45 0/1 * * ?

The first 45 signals the start at 45 minutes after the hour and the second the increments afterwards.  The 0/1 portion is the hourly interval